# Clang-Tidy: Resolving No Match error when adding Arguments

Tags: clang-tidy

I'm trying to get clang-tidy working to analyze my code. Currently, I have this command:

```
clang-tidy file.C -- -I/all/my/include/files -L/all/my/libs <any_other_args_i_need>
```

I'm assuming this works fine because I get this result:

```
End of search list.
12 warnings generated.
Suppressed 12 warnings (12 in non-user code).
Use -header-filter=.* to display errors from all non-system headers. Use -system-headers to display errors from system headers as well.
```

Now, when I add any other argument (i.e. `-checks=-*,clang-analyzer-*,-clang-analyzer-cplusplus*`), I get the error `clang-tidy: No match`. This error pops up when I add any other `-argument` in addition to my command above.

Does anyone know what this issue is?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue. For me it was a problem with the default settings for zsh, which I have recently installed.

This is from the zsh documentation:

> NOMATCH (+3)
> If a pattern for filename generation has no matches, print an error, instead of leaving it unchanged in the argument list. This also applies to file expansion of an initial `~' or` ='.

I think it's to stop people from typing things like `rm *` by accident, which I can see has it's merits although personally I prefer to live dangerously so I disabled it by adding `unsetopt nomatch` to the end of `~/.zshrc` then ran `source ~/.zshrc`.

If you prefer to stick with the default, you need to call clang-tidy as `noglob clang-tidy`.

If this is the case I would add `alias clang-tidy='noglob clang-tidy'` to your .zshrc file.